# Diferent result between Online C Compiler and MinGW compiler

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

i've a problem with linked list in C, i implement order insert function and when i build & run the program not work like i think, but if i compile this code in Online c Compiler, the program magically work.
This is My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list{
    int valore;
    struct list *next;
}typedef Nodo;


Nodo *nuovoElemento(int x);
Nodo *preInserimento(Nodo *top, int elemento);
Nodo *inserimentoInCoda(Nodo *top, int elemento);
Nodo *inserimentoInOrder(Nodo *top, int x);
void stampaLista(Nodo *top);

int main(){
    Nodo *top = NULL;
    int i,n,x;
    printf("\nQuanti elementi vuoi inserire: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\n\n Inserisci elemento: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        top=inserimentoInOrder(top, x);
    }
    stampaLista(top);

    return 0;
}


Nodo *nuovoElemento(int x){
    Nodo *tmp= (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    tmp->valore=x;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    return tmp;
}

Nodo *preInserimento(Nodo *top, int elemento){
    Nodo *tmp = nuovoElemento(elemento);
    tmp->next=top;
    return tmp;
}

Nodo *inserimentoInCoda(Nodo *top, int elemento){
    if(top==NULL)
        return nuovoElemento(elemento);
    else{
        top -> next = inserimentoInCoda(top -> next, elemento);
        return top;
    }
}

Nodo *inserimentoInOrder(Nodo *top, int x) {
    if (top == NULL || top -> valore > x) {
        Nodo *tmp = nuovoElemento(x);
        tmp -> next = top;
        top = tmp;
        return top;
    }
    else
        top -> next = inserimentoInOrder(top -> next, x);
}


void stampaLista(Nodo *top) {
    if (top != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", top -> valore);
        stampaLista(top -> next);
    }
    else
        printf("NULL\n");
}
```

[Online C Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoukr.png)

[MinGW on Windows - Same result in Lubuntu (NOT VIRTUAL MACHINE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ohH.png)

Comment: compile with warnings turned on: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.  `inserimentoInOrder` doesn't have a return statement in the `else` branch resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: You have not given both programs the same input - you must compare like with like - but anyway this kind of result can be a sympton of *undefined behaviour* somewhere in the code, so it sometimes behaves, sometimes does not.

Comment: @VRalf It is interesting why are there list instead of lista and vice versa valore instead of value?

Answer (score 1):

In the function inserimentoInOrder there is no return statement inside  the else part of the if statement.

The function can look like

```
Nodo *inserimentoInOrder(Nodo *top, int x) {
    if (top == NULL || top -> valore > x) {
        Nodo *tmp = nuovoElemento(x);
        tmp -> next = top;
        top = tmp;
    }
    else {
        top -> next = inserimentoInOrder(top -> next, x);
    }

    return top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !